# Adding event with reminders to calendar with 'Intent.putExtra()' way of doing

Tags: android, events, calendar, reminders

I'm trying to add events to calendar with the following code :

```
public Intent calPopulation()
{
        Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, this._title);

        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(this._year,this._month, this._day, this._hour, this._minute);
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, calDate.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, CalendarContract.Events._ID);
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.ALLOWED_REMINDERS, "METHOD_DEFAULT");
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);

        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES,5);
        return calIntent;
}
```

And then launch the action with : `startActivity(mTask.calPopulation());`

I don't have any issue, the calendar app event launched with the correct information I entered into my app, except that it does not fill in the event the reminder I would like to add.

Do you have any clues? I tried to search within many threads using this method (I mean the  intent.putExtra) but never find anything interesting.

Other point, is there a way to directly save the event + reminder into the calendar without opening calendar App and requesting for user action?

Thanks in advance.
Alex.

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: Hi, my goal is to set reminders in the same time I'm adding an event to the calendar. With my given example, the reminder is not existing in the calendar after starting the activity.

Comment: Did you manage to get this right? While still using `Intent` and not directly adding it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No answer according to the method I pointed out, but another way I found to add event with reminders to the calendar.

Hereunder methods are working fine for me :

```
// Add an event to the calendar of the user.
    public void addEvent(Context context) {
        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(this._year, this._month, this._day, this._hour, this._minute);

        try {
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calDate.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, this._title);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeZone().getID());
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());
            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            // Save the eventId into the Task object for possible future delete.
            this._eventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            // Add a 5 minute, 1 hour and 1 day reminders (3 reminders)
            setReminder(cr, this._eventId, 5);
            setReminder(cr, this._eventId, 60);
            setReminder(cr, this._eventId, 1440);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // routine to add reminders with the event
    public void setReminder(ContentResolver cr, long eventID, int timeBefore) {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, timeBefore);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values);
            Cursor c = CalendarContract.Reminders.query(cr, eventID,
                    new String[]{CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES});
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                System.out.println("calendar"
                        + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES)));
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // function to remove an event from the calendar using the eventId stored within the Task object.
    public void removeEvent(Context context) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

        int iNumRowsDeleted = 0;

        Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(CALENDAR_URI_BASE+"events");
        Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, this._eventId);
        iNumRowsDeleted = cr.delete(eventUri, null, null);

        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Deleted " + iNumRowsDeleted + " calendar entry.");
    }


    public int updateEvent(Context context) {
        int iNumRowsUpdated = 0;
        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(this._year, this._month, this._day, this._hour, this._minute);

        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, this._title);
        event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calDate.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);

        Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(CALENDAR_URI_BASE+"events");
        Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, this._eventId);

        iNumRowsUpdated = context.getContentResolver().update(eventUri, event, null,
                null);

        // TODO put text into strings.xml
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Updated " + iNumRowsUpdated + " calendar entry.");

        return iNumRowsUpdated;
    }
```

Hope this could help others that encountered the same problem I had :).

Alex.

Comment: This method adds event directly to the calendar, therefore requires calendar reading/writing permissions. 
For us who prefer using intent for sending event information to calendar app, is there any way to prepopulate the "reminder" data on event creation screen?

Comment: I have directly created a calendar event through my app and added reminder also. They are working perfectly. But when I click reminder notification, it's opening device calendar event. Now I want to customize reminder notification to load my app without loading default calendar. Can I achieve this ?

Comment: @Alexandre What is CALENDAR_URI_BASE in removeEvent & updateEvent methods?

Comment: Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values); Throws SqliteException on M

Comment: @Amardeep did you find the solution for SqliteException?

Comment: @SurajPohwani We have to find the primary calendar first instead of using 1 as CALENDAR_ID. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073427/unable-to-add-create-reminder-for-calendar-event-on-marshmallow-device/40074288#40074288

Comment: you aren't using intents, you need WRITE permission for that

Comment: @Singed did you find solution using intent?

Comment: @user924 no, sorry - this was 5 years ago I don't even remember

Answer (score 2):

Agree with above answer but important is calender Id. you can not use 1 as Samsung phone uses 1 for their calendar(S Planner). So calendar ID is the id for which email you want the event. You can get calendar id by following code for a specific event

```
int calenderId=-1;
        String calenderEmaillAddress="xxx@gmail.com";
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
                CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME};
        ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), projection,
                CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + "=? and (" +
                        CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME + "=? or " +
                        CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME + "=?)",
                new String[]{calenderEmaillAddress, calenderEmaillAddress,
                        calenderEmaillAddress}, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            if (cursor.getString(1).equals(calenderEmaillAddress))
                 calenderId=cursor.getInt(0); //youre calender id to be insered in above  answer


        }
```