# Insert event into android calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I'm using this code to insert an event into calendar in android:

```
    private void insertEvent(int start, int end, String location, String comment, String title) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

    values.put("calendar_id", 1);
    values.put("title", title);
    values.put("description",  comment);
    values.put("eventLocation", location);
    values.put("dtstart", start);
    values.put("dtend", end);
    values.put("allDay", 0);
    values.put("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    values.put("eventTimezone", tz.getID());

    Uri l_eventUri;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
        // the old way
        l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    } else {
        // the new way
        l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    }
    Uri l_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver()
            .insert(l_eventUri, values);
}
```

Here is another try:

```
private void insertEvent2(int start, int end, String location, String comment, String title){

    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    ContentValues eventsArray = new ContentValues();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,start);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,end);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, title);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,location);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        eventsArray = values;
    Uri l_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver()
            .insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

But I can't see the events I have created when I see the default android calendar. Have you any idea how should I do insert an event?

Comment: see these two links [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14056064/6518860) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28813990/6518860)

Comment: Thank you. My code is the same as in the first link but I will try the second one too.

Answer (score 0):

use contact resolver to add events on calendar

```
ContentResolver cr = Env.currentActivity.getContentResolver();
                    ContentValues[] eventsArray = new ContentValues[projectDataList.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < projectDataList.size(); i++) {
                        projectDetailData = projectDataList.get(i);
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, (long) (Util.dateToMiliSec(shift_start_date) + (Util.convertTimeIntoSecound(projectDetailData.shift_start_time, "HH:mm:ss") * 1000)));
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, (long) (Util.dateToMiliSec(shift_end_date) + (Util.convertTimeIntoSecound(projectDetailData.shift_end_time, "HH:mm:ss") * 1000)));
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, title);
                        values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, work_location);
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Env.currentActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        eventsArray[i] = values;
                    }
                    int a = cr.bulkInsert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventsArray);
```

Comment: There is no error it's just not inserting into the calendar.

Comment: I edited my code but I don't need array so I deleted it from your code.