# Unable to add create reminder for Calendar event on Marshmallow Device

Tags: android

Can someone help me to create a reminder for an calendar event on programmatically. It works perfectly fine on API level 22, but not on 23 (Marshmallow).

**Code**:

```
ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();
reminderValues.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, 1);
reminderValues.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 1); 
reminderValues.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_DEFAULT);
Uri reminderUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                    .insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminderValues);
```

**Exception**:

> SqliteDoneException

Answer (score 1):

```
private int getPrimaryCalendar() {
    // noinspection ResourceType
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{
            CalendarContract.Calendars._ID, CalendarContract.Calendars.IS_PRIMARY}, null, null, null);

    int calID = 0;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (managedCursor != null && managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                calID = managedCursor.getInt(managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Calendars._ID));
                int columnIndex = -1;
                try {
                    columnIndex = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Calendars.IS_PRIMARY);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    LogUtil.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                if (columnIndex != -1 && managedCursor.getInt(columnIndex) == 1) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    calID = 1;
                }
            } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
            managedCursor.close();
        }
    }

    return calID;
}
```

> Use the default calendar

Comment: Handled the Null Check Exception.

Comment: @Amardeep when debugged `managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Calendars.IS_PRIMARY);` getColumnIndex is throwing `NullPointerException` with `columnIndex` value 0.
what could be reason?
While adding events, everytime calID returned is 20 only.